# Post-installation PHP crash

Tags: 8

I decided to give a shy try to Drupal 8. Installation went quite smooth, but when everything was ready to hit the home page I was delighted with the following error:

> CRASH: PHP segmentation violation in method_exists() called at [/core/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:72], in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver::getController() called at [/core/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:117], in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel::handleRaw() called at [/core/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:73], in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel::handle() called at [/core/lib/Drupal/Core/HttpKernel.php:52], in Drupal\Core\HttpKernel::handle() called at [/core/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:197], in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::handle() called at [/core/includes/bootstrap.inc:2208], in drupal_handle_request() called at [/index.php:12]

How would I go about solving this? Is that something of a Drupal programming error? Is that something that depends on final configuration? I kind of don't believe this would massively occur to all people, so I assume it might be caused by something in my setup.

I'm running PHP 5.3.21 with a local php.ini setting the magic quotes flags to off.
Due to the hosting, I had to comment out the htaccess bottom part for gzip compression, if that matters.

Comment: Since this is a bug in PHP, I am closing it as off-topic.

Comment: If you have APC enabled, try uninstalling it completely, restarting apache to see if that helps (it did for me when something very similar happened). If that works you should be able to enable APC again after that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PHP `segmentation violation` is a PHP bug. You can not solve this at the PHP, or Drupal level, this needs a bug report for PHP itself, [here](https://bugs.php.net/).

Segmentation violation means that PHP somehow mismanaged it's memory, which is impossible to directly cause with PHP code, since [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29) aren't available.

Notice though that there are two releases of 5.3 after the one you're running, upgrading should be your action, as a problem in `method_exists()` should have gotten a lot of attention, and is hopefully already fixed.

Comment: Thanks, Letharion. That's usually the case with me. Thousands of people successfully developing modules for D8, but when I decide to jump up the bandwagon, I hit the wall. So, seems like submitting the bug to Symfony is clueless, right?

Comment: Yeah, developers working with PHP can't help with this. You need a developer working _on_ PHP for this. You should try upgrading to 5.3.23, or even 5.4 though, as your problem could be solved already.

Comment: Could be something as simple as an APC problem though, this has happened to me before

Comment: That makes sense. Even just restarting the webserver to force an apc cache clear _might_ help then.